# Does hypercall take the same time as a linux system call?

Tags: linux, xen, system-calls

From Xen website,

> A hypercall is to a syscall what a hypervisor is to an OS.
>   Alternatively, a hypercall is to a hypervisor what a syscall is to a
>   kernel. A hypercall is a software trap from a domain to the
>   hypervisor, just as a syscall is a software trap from an application
>   to the kernel. Domains will use hypercalls to request privileged
>   operations like updating pagetables. Like a syscall, the hypercall is
>   synchronous, but the return path from the hypervisor to the domain
>   uses event channels. An event channel is a queue of asynchronous
>   notifications, and notify of the same sorts of events that interrupts
>   notify on native hardware. When a domain with pending events in its
>   queue is scheduled, the OS's event-callback handler is called to take
>   appropriate action.

- Does the hypercall take the same time as a syscall assuming both of them are doing the same thing.
- Is there any difference in the way hypervisor handles a hypercall than a linux kernel which handles the system call in the same way

Answer (score 0):

A hypercall is slower than a syscall. This is because the hypercall has to first reach the host/hypervisor and then navigate its way to the CPU in order to get executed. Likewise for the return path. In fact, benchmarks on a similar kernel, the [Hyperkernel](https://locore.cs.washington.edu/hyperkernel/) have shown that a hypercall takes about 3 to 4 times longer (linked page's pdf page 15).